# output file not saved on my bucket, in AWS s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am trying to follow this tutorial from AWS. I am at the quick example step.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/submitting-user-applications-with-spark-submit/

When I try to run the command:

`aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-xxxxx --steps Type=spark,Name=SparkWordCountApp,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false,--num-executors,5,--executor-cores,5,--executor-memory,20g,s3://codelocation/wordcount.py,s3://inputbucket/input.txt,s3://outputbucket/],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE`

my output file does not appear on my bucket even though on the EMR, it says that the job is completed.

```
SparkWordCountApp   Completed   2017-01-24 16:35 (UTC+1)    10 seconds
```

This is the wordcount python file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: wordcount  ", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
    text_file = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    counts.saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
    sc.stop()
```

This is log file from the cluster:

```
17/01/25 14:40:19 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
17/01/25 14:40:19 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (11520 MB per container)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (20480+2048 MB) is above the max threshold (11520 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.verifyClusterResources(Client.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1178)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I am using the m3.x large instance.

Comment: What is the value set for `spark.executor.memory`?

Comment: From the command line, it is 20g.

Comment: Yea, you have already mentioned it, I missed it. Per m3.xlarge instance has only 15g but executor requests 20g+2g, moreover yarn configuration allows maximum of 11.5g only. Can you please reduce it to 8g and try running it?

Comment: @franklinsijo, I have tried. The python file executed fine but I still have no output file.

Comment: Is the outputbucket created already? and your input.txt is not empty right?

Comment: @franklinsijo, the output bucket is created. input.txt is not empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134007/discussion-between-franklinsijo-and-ray-r-chua).

Comment: @franklinsijo, let me know if you are available for a chat.

Answer (score 0):

try making the output directory a subdirectory, rather than the root one. Without speaking for the EMR s3 client, I know that the Hadoop S3A one has had some issues in the past related to rename() when the destination was the root of a bucket. Otherwise, crank up the logs and see what gets printed from the com.aws modules

Comment: I have added the log file to my question.